# FullCalendar events which begin on a day where they are hidden shows +More options on empty calendar days in Month View

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

First time using FullCalendar v4.1.0

I thought I had everything working well, but I have run into a problem. I have set my events to all have `overlap = true` as desired by the business requirements. The problem now is that I have let's say 5 events which stretch from Monday - Friday. Then on Thursday I have 2 more events which span from Thursday - Sunday. On days Saturday and Sunday it will show the +more link instead of displaying the events which started on Thursday as they are hidden from view under the 5 events which started on Monday because of the `eventLimit` property. Does anyone know how to make these events which begin on Thursday display in days Saturday and Sunday instead of as the +More link button.

I've been reading through the FullCalendar documentation but am having trouble finding any calendar options that apply to my particular situation.

Comment: you could always change the eventLimit value??

Comment: @ADyson You are correct. But business requirements are to only display x number of events per calendar day.

Comment: then you have contradictory requirements, unfortunately

Comment: @ADyson Are you familiar with FullCalendar? If not, thank you for the edit and suggestion.

Comment: Yes I'm very familiar with it. Take at look at my answer history :-). And my opinion is that you can't do what you want, without changing the eventLimit

Comment: @ADyson Ok. Thank you. :)